# Loading JSON data from server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am currently using knockout.js framework. I have taken a basic contacts form [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html) and modified to my own needs. I can store the values in my database. I am have difficulties loading the values from the server. I have two contacts saved. When loading the values, it shows two fields for contacts but with empty values. I am checking on the console log the ajax request and it is returning values. How can I properly load the values from server?[DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/insert_person.php)

```
var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
    var self = this;
    self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
            firstName: contact.firstName,
            lastName: contact.lastName,
            phone: contact.phone,
            alt_phone: contact.alt_phone,
            main1: ko.observable(contact.main1),
            main2: ko.observable(contact.main2)
        };
    }));



    self.addContact = function () {
        self.contacts.push({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            phone: "",
            alt_phone: "",
            main1: false,
            main2: false
        });
    };

    self.removeContact = function (contact) {
        self.contacts.remove(contact);
    };

    self.addPhone = function (contact) {
        contact.phones.push({
            number: ""
        });
    };

    self.removePhone = function (phone) {
        $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
            this.phones.remove(phone)
        })
    };

    self.save = function () {
            self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.contacts), null, 2));
        };


    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("");


};

$.getJSON("functions/getPerson.php", function(allData) {
          var initialData = $.map(allData, function(person) { return new ContactsModel(person) });
          ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line:
`var initialData = $.map(allData, function(person) { return new ContactsModel(person) });`

And try to use `ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(allData));` (with allData).

Instead of: `ko.applyBindings(new ContactsModel(initialData));`

Comment: Oh perfect, I must have understood it all wrong then.